# Inconsistent rendering of opacity in <G> element on Android and iOS using react-native-svg

Tags: android, ios, react-native, svg, react-native-svg

When using the <G> element with an opacity attribute, the rendering of nested elements inside the <G> element is inconsistent between Android and iOS platforms.

Here's a minimal code snippet that reproduces the issue:

```
import { Svg, G, Circle, Rect } from "react-native-svg";

export function Overlap() {
    return (
        <Svg>
            <G opacity={0.5} translateX={100} translateY={200}>
                <Circle r="40" fill="black" />
                <Rect width="80" height="60" fill="green" />
            </G>
        </Svg>
    )
}
```

This is the result [on Android emulator (Pixel_6_Pro_API_33)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXW01.png), and you can see the right-bottom part of the circle through the rectangle.

This is the result [on iOS simulator (iPhone 14 Pro)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEHdJ.png), which is my expectation, the contents of the group to first be composited and then the result to be lowered in opacity.

How can I achieve the iOS result on Android?

Thank you!